# How to detect invalid audio hardware (XNA, C#)

Tags: c#, audio, exception, xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to automatically disable audio in cases where no audio hardware is present (C#, XNA, Visual Studio). The current code version throws a "NoAudioHardwareException" but does not properly enter the catch branch as expected.

```
            try
            {
                SoundEffect.MasterVolume = 1f;
            }
            catch (NoAudioHardwareException e)
            {
                Warning.Happened("No valid sound device found. Disable sound.");
                DebugEngine.disableSound = true;
            }
```

Also, see [here](http://hybridbeasts.com/error2.jpg) for the VisualStudio output.

Comment: It's a strange behaviour. Maybe You didn't build Your project before debugging and it still use the old version ? Try also to add catch(Exception ex) to see if it hits it.

Comment: Thanks for for answer. I check both of your suggestion but without success. catch(Exception ex) is also not hit.

Comment: That's extremely strange.